# "Connect to a wireless display" in Project menu

Tags: windows

This might be a bit of a stupid question, but I don't have Wireshark or another computer to test this at the moment. Does the "Connect to a wireless display" feature in Windows 10 use some kind of ad-hoc network connection between the devices, or does it work over the local network? Does it work only with devices with wireless cards or can I stream from a desktop that's connected by Ethernet to a tablet PC?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Intel WiDi page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26793/Intel-Widi) Windows 8.1 and 10 are supporting [Miracast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) natively.

And as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast)

> Miracast employs the peer-to-peer Wi-Fi Direct standard.

So, it appears that the wireless display is via ad-hoc network.

Comment: Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt796768.aspx) work over Ethernet?